# REST image upload returning empty json body

Tags: marketing-cloud, rest, ssjs, images, base64

Trying my first rest API call with SSJS. I'm trying to upload an image as per this guide https://sfmarketing.cloud/2020/02/29/create-a-cloudpages-form-with-an-image-file-upload-option/

On my landing page i'm just trying to console.log a response, but the response is a 200 OK with an empty JSON body, and no image is uploaded. I've reviewed the code, and don't really know how to proceed. I've checked that the correct values are being sent to the SSJS handler.

Here's the part of my landingpage javascript posting to my SSJS code resource:

```
    function sendToSFMC(base64, assetName) {
    console.log(base64);
    console.log(assetName);
    fetch("cloudpageURL", {  //provide URL of the processing page
                  method: "POST",
                  headers: {
                      "Content-Type": "application/json"
                  },
                  body: JSON.stringify({
                      base64enc: base64,
                      fileName: assetName,
                      assetName: "png"
                  })
              })
              .then(function(res) {
                      console.log(res);
                      window.alert("Success!");
              })
              .catch(function(err) {
                  window.alert("Error!");
              });
};
```

And here's my SSJS handling the request and posting to SFMC REST api

```
    <script runat="server">
Platform.Load("Core","1");
HTTPHeader.SetValue("Access-Control-Allow-Methods","POST");
HTTPHeader.SetValue("Access-Control-Allow-Origin","*");
try {
    //fetch posted data
    var jsonData = Platform.Request.GetPostData();
    var obj = Platform.Function.ParseJSON(jsonData);
    //prepare data for API call
    var base64enc = obj.base64enc;
    var fileName = obj.fileName;
    var assetName = obj.assetName;
    //match asset type with uploaded file (https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/base-asset-types.htm)
    var assetTypes = { ai: 16, psd: 17, pdd: 18, eps: 19, gif: 20, jpe: 21, jpeg: 22, jpg: 23, jp2: 24, jpx: 25, pict: 26, pct: 27, png: 28, tif: 29, tiff: 30, tga: 31, bmp: 32, wmf: 33, vsd: 34, pnm: 35, pgm: 36, pbm: 37, ppm: 38, svg: 39, "3fr": 40, ari: 41, arw: 42, bay: 43, cap: 44, crw: 45, cr2: 46, dcr: 47, dcs: 48, dng: 49, drf: 50, eip: 51, erf: 52, fff: 53, iiq: 54, k25: 55, kdc: 56, mef: 57, mos: 58, mrw: 59, nef: 60, nrw: 61, orf: 62, pef: 63, ptx: 64, pxn: 65, raf: 66, raw: 67, rw2: 68, rwl: 69, rwz: 70, srf: 71, sr2: 72, srw: 73, x3f: 74, "3gp": 75, "3gpp": 76, "3g2": 77, "3gp2": 78, asf: 79, avi: 80, m2ts: 81, mts: 82, dif: 83, dv: 84, mkv: 85, mpg: 86, f4v: 87, flv: 88, mjpg: 89, mjpeg: 90, mxf: 91, mpeg: 92, mp4: 93, m4v: 94, mp4v: 95, mov: 96, swf: 97, wmv: 98, rm: 99, ogv: 100, indd: 101, indt: 102, incx: 103, wwcx: 104, doc: 105, docx: 106, dot: 107, dotx: 108, mdb: 109, mpp: 110, ics: 111, xls: 112, xlsx: 113, xlk: 114, xlsm: 115, xlt: 116, xltm: 117, csv: 118, tsv: 119, tab: 120, pps: 121, ppsx: 122, ppt: 123, pptx: 124, pot: 125, thmx: 126, pdf: 127, ps: 128, qxd: 129, rtf: 130, sxc: 131, sxi: 132, sxw: 133, odt: 134, ods: 135, ots: 136, odp: 137, otp: 138, epub: 139, dvi: 140, key: 141, keynote: 142, pez: 143, aac: 144, m4a: 145, au: 146, aif: 147, aiff: 148, aifc: 149, mp3: 150, wav: 151, wma: 152, midi: 153, oga: 154, ogg: 155, ra: 156, vox: 157, voc: 158, "7z": 159, arj: 160, bz2: 161, cab: 162, gz: 163, gzip: 164, iso: 165, lha: 166, sit: 167, tgz: 168, jar: 169, rar: 170, tar: 171, zip: 172, gpg: 173, htm: 174, html: 175, xhtml: 176, xht: 177, css: 178, less: 179, sass: 180, js: 181, json: 182, atom: 183, rss: 184, xml: 185, xsl: 186, xslt: 187, md: 188, markdown: 189, as: 190, fla: 191, eml: 192, text: 193, txt: 194, freeformblock: 195, textblock: 196, htmlblock: 197, textplusimageblock: 198, imageblock: 199, abtestblock: 200, dynamicblock: 201, stylingblock: 202, einsteincontentblock: 203, webpage: 205, webtemplate: 206, templatebasedemail: 207, htmlemail: 208, textonlyemail: 209, socialshareblock: 210, socialfollowblock: 211, buttonblock: 212, layoutblock: 213, defaulttemplate: 214, smartcaptureblock: 215, smartcaptureformfieldblock: 216, smartcapturesubmitoptionsblock: 217, slotpropertiesblock: 218, externalcontentblock: 219, codesnippetblock: 220, rssfeedblock: 221, formstylingblock: 222, referenceblock: 223, imagecarouselblock: 224, customblock: 225, liveimageblock: 226, livesettingblock: 227, contentmap: 228, jsonmessage: 230 };
    var assetTypeID = assetTypes[assetName];
    //authenticate to get access token
    var authEndpoint = 'endpoint' //add authentication endpoint
    var payload = {
        client_id: "id", //pass Client ID
        client_secret: "secret", //pass Client Secret
        grant_type: "client_credentials"
    };
    var url = authEndpoint + '/v2/token'
    var contentType = 'application/json'
    var accessTokenRequest = HTTP.Post(url, contentType, Stringify(payload));
    if (accessTokenRequest.StatusCode == 200) {
        var tokenResponse = Platform.Function.ParseJSON(accessTokenRequest.Response[0]);
        var accessToken = tokenResponse.access_token
        var rest_instance_url = tokenResponse.rest_instance_url
    }
    //make api call to create asset
    if (base64enc != null) {
        var headerNames = ["Authorization"];
        var headerValues = ["Bearer " + accessToken];
        var jsonBody = {
            "name": fileName,
            "assetType": {
                "name": assetName,
                "id": assetTypeID
            },
            "file": base64enc
        };
        var requestUrl = rest_instance_url + "asset/v1/content/assets"
        var createAsset = HTTP.Post(requestUrl, contentType, Stringify(jsonBody), headerNames, headerValues);
      Write(Stringify(Platform.Function.ParseJSON(createAsset.Response[0])))
    }
} catch (error) {
    Write("<br>error: " + Stringify(error));
}
</script>
```

Comment: I am under the impression that you can't `console.log` with SSJS as it is run server-side. 

This should be rendering something though: `Write(Stringify(Platform.Function.ParseJSON(createAsset.Response[0])))`

I would check and see if your marketing cloud application has the correct privileges to Read and Write Documents and Images.

Comment: Hi Nate. I'm only logging to console in my client-side script, which should recieve the response from the SSJS handler page :-) I've checked that it has r/w acces to documents and images.